# Drupal 8 - How do I get rid of link rel=delete-form, edit-form and other in the head?

Tags: drupal, drupal-8, drupal-taxonomy

I get bot traffic to all the `<link rel="something">` tags. The 'somethings' include 'canonical', 'shortlink', 'delete-form', 'edit-form', 'version-history'

Because those links printed even for anonymous users

Found this https://www.drupal.org/node/2782363
Updated to 8.2.1, but still got this links on taxonomy term pages.

Answer (score 2):

You must use `hook_page_attachments_alter()` to change this information. Check the [documentation](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21lib%21Drupal%21Core%21Render%21theme.api.php/function/hook_page_attachments_alter/8.1.x) for more info.

The information you want to remove will be in the array that is passed as a parameter to this hook.

It will be on `$page['#attached']['html_head_link']`

```
function YOURTHEME_page_attachments_alter(array &$attachments) {
    print_r($attachments['#attached']['html_head_link']);
}
```

Comment: Thanks for answer, but can you give me more detailed information how to delete '<link rel="shortlink" href="/link" />
<link rel="delete-form" href="/link" />
<link rel="edit-form" href="/link" />
<link rel="devel-render" href="/link" />
<link rel="devel-load" href="/link" />
<link rel="display" href="/link" />
<link rel="devel-markup" href="/link" />
<link rel="token-devel" href="/link" />' from taxonomy term page for anonymous users?

Answer (score 0):

Found working solution, 
module https://github.com/enjoyiacm/unset_html_head_link